# Android - cannot view map Google Maps API

Tags: android, android-layout, android-maps, google-maps-mobile

I have a problem with google maps API on my android application.
before all was normal, and the application can display the map. I published the apk and follow all tahap2 correctly.

I install applications on my smartphone. but after a week or more all of a sudden my application can not display the map. only the grid view only.

if anyone can give me a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance

DevYudh

Comment: have you registered for a Map api key (a release key not a debug one)??

Comment: Any errors or relevant warnings in log?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in the past. You have to register a Google Maps API key. (Not the debug one). Debug key only works when you are testing the app. But when you publish the app in the market, you need to use the release key. That will surely solve your problem.

See it here..

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Answer (score 0):

for display google map on android device, the map key and apk file's sign key must match.
If you debugging, map key must be made by debug key's fingerprint. and the other side, for deploying apk map key must be made by deploying key's fingerprint.